# SQL Server header character replacement

Tags: sql-server, csv, replace, tabs, header

In a select statement in T-SQL, how does one ensure a certain character is not used in the header creation for saving to a flat (CSV) file?  I can delimit it with a comma just fine, but the Select query always seems to want to add a tab for the headers whenever i open it up in either Notepad or Notepad++.

Comment: You are saying that you save the results to CSV and you see a tab only the headers?

Comment: No, i am saying i can see both the delimited commas and the tabs that SQL inserts upon the selection query.

Comment: Are you copying the data from SSMS, (copy with headers)?

Comment: You can turn off the header then do select col1,col2, etc from dual union all select col1, col2, etc from table;

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is an option in SSMS to remove the tabs in results to file. However, you can concatenate the results into one column, deliminating them as you please.